Buddypress display only suggestion group in sidebar
i want show only suggestion group list in sidebar widget in buddypress. any suggest free plugin or function in wordpress for buddypress ?
worpress ver : 6.7
buddypress :  14.2.1

You can try this plugin:
BuddyPress Featured Groups
https://wordpress.org/plugins/bp-featured-groups/
The BuddyPress Featured Groups plugin allows for an enjoyable experience in creating and displaying lists of featured groups.
It is highly flexible in how the lists are displayed (slider, list, theme default, or custom).
Additionally, it provides a simple API for marking/unmarking groups as featured.

when i install this plugin show this error. https://prnt.sc/YFWchXWRELfU

It seems there are currently some issues with how the plugin is displayed on the widget.
Perhaps you can contact the plugin author directly:
https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/bp-featured-groups/

If your requirements are not too complex,
you might consider modifying the following code based on your needs to create a custom plugin that suits your requirements:
https://github.com/sbrajesh/bp-group-suggest

According to the documentation:
https://buddyuser.com/plugin-bp-featured-groups
You can also use a shortcode to place it directly in a widget.
For example, refer to the following screenshot:
https://i.imgur.com/KLfW2o5.png
For a live example, you can check:
https://wpdev.wantnote.com/

thanks for reply hank ku. once let me check.

No problem. If you have any questions, feel free to bring them up for discussion.

hello hank ku, today i added with shortcode : https://prnt.sc/TXpI0IHs6DQU
wp admin side setting : https://prnt.sc/XXrl76zWfR4s
frontend not showing : https://prnt.sc/NM0jijbT8nqd

Hi, there are two things:


Manually set the Feature Group. It will only appear in the shortcode after it's been set, as shown in the screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/o4HjyNb.png


In the shortcode, double quotes must use " instead of ”.



thanks for your reply Hank ku. yes i fixed quotes.
is feature group and suggestion group functionality are same or different ?? kindly let me know.

kindly check your linkedin profile. i had sent you request.

As far as I know, BP Featured Groups
https://wordpress.org/plugins/bp-featured-groups/
does not have a recommendation feature; it simply displays the Featured Groups you have set.
If you need a recommendation feature, you might consider modifying the following plugin:
https://github.com/sbrajesh/bp-group-suggest
